# Angular Services not passing Value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to get a simple random generator using Angular services between controllers. So far:

**JS. FILE**

```
var myServiceModule = angular.module('myServiceModule',[]);

myServiceModule.controller('SecondController',['$scope','randomizer', function($scope,randomizer){
    $scope.initialNumber = 0;
    console.log('Initial number in second controller: ' + $scope.initialNumber);
    $scope.generateRandom = function(rng){
        console.log('called w/ ' + rng );
        $scope.initialNumber = randomizer.genRan(rng);
        console.log('Randomed: ' + $scope.initialNumber);
    }
}]);

myServiceModule.service('randomizer',[function(range){
    this.genRan = function(){
        console.log('inside genRan');
        return (Math.floor(Math.random() * range) + 1 ); 
    }
}]);
```

**HTML File**

```
<div id="second" ng-controller="SecondController">
<label>Press button to Generate a random number between 1-100:</label>
    <button ng-click="generateRandom(100);">Generate</button>
</div>
```

### My Console output is as follows:

1. Initial number in second controller: 0
2. called w/ 100
3. inside genRan
4. Randomed: NaN

---

There should be a value passed when I call the service correct? Instead I keep getting NaN for a value when the Service function call (.genRan) is invoked. I am new to services, the function is being called properly but why isn't a value being returned to the Controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `range` should be defined as a parameter in the `genRan` function, try this:

```
myServiceModule.service('randomizer', [function() {
    this.genRan = function(range) {
        console.log('inside genRan');
        return (Math.floor(Math.random() * range) + 1 ); 
    }
}]);
```

Comment: That worked. Why wouldn't the scope of the service function allow for the inner function to use the range variable though. Doesn't JS extend outward until it hits a suitable variable?

Comment: @Jeeves The inner function was using the `range` variable, it's just that it's undefined. That place is for injection parameters. For example, you could inject a service called 'range'.

Answer (score 0):

You missed passing the Range that is passed to the service inside the this.genRan Function, please modify your code and pass the range like this :

```
myServiceModule.service('randomizer',[function(range){
    this.genRan = function(range){
        console.log('inside genRan');
        console.log(range);
        return (Math.floor(Math.random() * range) + 1 ); 
    }
}]);
```